# Cannot scan a local (unpushed) image for CVEs with Anchore Grype - workarounds

Tags: docker, security, docker-image, cve, grype

Apparently it is not possible to perform a security scan for vulnerabilities in a Docker image using Anchore Grype unless that image was previously pushed to a registry.

This makes it currently unsuitable for gating your registry from vulnerable images, because an image can be pushed there and then - before your scan is complete - this infected image with some severe CVEs can be immediately pulled by an unsuspecting user (before the image gets withdrawn).

How to work around this problem?

---

To reproduce the problem

1. First `docker build` an image; do not push it to the registry.
2. Try to scan the locally available image with `grype` and you will get an error like this:

```
$ ./scan-with-grype-dockerized.sh mirekphd/ml-cache:20230726
[0000]  INFO grype version: 0.64.2
1 error occurred:
    * failed to catalog: unable to load image: unable to use OciRegistry source: failed to get image descriptor from registry: GET https://index.docker.io/v2/mirekphd/ml-cache/manifests/20230726: MANIFEST_UNKNOWN: manifest unknown; unknown tag=20230726
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you may consider running `grype` as the `root` user (please test it on an image that wasn't previously pushed to the Docker Hub):

```
$ docker run --rm --name grype -u 0 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock anchore/grype:latest --only-fixed mirekphd/ml-cache:20230731 

NAME          INSTALLED  FIXED-IN   TYPE  VULNERABILITY  SEVERITY 
libcrypto1.1  1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r0  apk   CVE-2022-4304  Medium    
libcrypto1.1  1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r0  apk   CVE-2022-4450  High      
libcrypto1.1  1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r0  apk   CVE-2023-0215  High      
libcrypto1.1  1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r0  apk   CVE-2023-0286  High      
libcrypto1.1  1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r1  apk   CVE-2023-0464  High      
libcrypto1.1  1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r2  apk   CVE-2023-0465  Medium    
libcrypto1.1  1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1u-r0  apk   CVE-2023-2650  High      
libcrypto1.1  1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1u-r2  apk   CVE-2023-3446  Medium    
libssl1.1     1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r0  apk   CVE-2022-4304  Medium    
libssl1.1     1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r0  apk   CVE-2022-4450  High      
libssl1.1     1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r0  apk   CVE-2023-0215  High      
libssl1.1     1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r0  apk   CVE-2023-0286  High      
libssl1.1     1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r1  apk   CVE-2023-0464  High      
libssl1.1     1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1t-r2  apk   CVE-2023-0465  Medium    
libssl1.1     1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1u-r0  apk   CVE-2023-2650  High      
libssl1.1     1.1.1s-r0  1.1.1u-r2  apk   CVE-2023-3446  Medium
```

Note: if you got Critical vulnerabilities above by not using the `--only-fixed` flag here, then be assured that they are relevant only for systems other than Alpine actually used in that image - one for Debian and one for... Windows, in a separate bug I've already reported to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

A safer and quite performant workaround is to use [`skopeo`](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) and its ability to copy unpushed local images (without the need to `docker run` them and the risk of altering them that `docker save` would impose) from the local Docker daemon (using the `docker-daemon:` prefix, note: no slashes there, unlike in the standard - remote registry - prefix of `docker://`) to copy the image in the OCI dir format to a temporary location, and then scan it there with `grype` using its `oci-dir:` prefix.